# Fatal error: Class 'CDbTestCase' not found

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, composer-php

I'm new in php and I have to do the testing for an app. I'm trying to make unit testing but an error messages is displayed. I have many weeks ago and I cannot fix it, please help me!!

The message says: Fatal error: Class 'CDbTestCase' not found.

I read and follow many tutorials about this issue but it doesn't work.

I'm using Yii, Eclipse IDE and Composer.

I think the problem is in bootstrap.php but I don't use it because I'm working with composer, this is the composer.json

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii": "1.1.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2",
        "codeception/codeception":"*",
        "phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.2"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "vendor/autoload.php"},
        "psr-4": {"": "/../framework/test/CDbTestCase.php"}
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put code where you got error?

Comment: it simply states that some where you are trying to create an object of `CDbTestCase`, but no where a class with this name is defined in your code. thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the errors I can't be sure, but maybe this answer will help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760644/fatal-error-class-cdbtestcase-not-found-yii-framework

Comment: I already checked the question above but it doesn't work. The header of my class is: class Impresora extends CActiveRecord and the erros is in test case header: class ImpresoraTest extends CDbTestCase

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap file is needed to load the yii framework. CDbTestCase is part of the yii framework so failing to include yii will give you this error if your tests depend on yii's unit test related classes.

Use the included bootstrap file and make sure you also include composer's autoload.php file. I normally add this to my yii config file (I believe by default, yii uses the test.php config file for custom testing related settings. You can include autoload.php inside this file)

Somewhere at the top of your yii config file

```
// Include composer autoload
require_once 'path/to/composer/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Composer autoloading is completely wrong.

1. Don't include the composer autoloader "vendor/autoload.php" in the autoloading of your own `composer.json`. There is only one autoloader, and it is created using your autoload data as well as any libraries.
2. The PSR-4 autoloading is also wrong. You have to state a directory where classes are put into files according to PSR-4. You point to one single file.
3. You don't use class prefixes for PSR-0 and PSR-4. This is bad for performance, because you are stating that ANY class could be in the directory. So Composer has to search for that class in this directory as well, even for classes that are guaranteed to not be there. Always use a prefix, and make it as long as possible to allow unique matches: One prefix should only ever point to exactly one directory structure.

You should explain why you don't use a bootstrap file in your tests. The minimal required bootstrap code for PHPUnit is to include the Composer autoloader. Additionally, you should add things that are required in your tests and have to be done once, like initialization of framework components -YMMV.

Comment: Now I have to use my imagination to guess what your code is - or I can ask you to provide a code example, reduced to only demonstrate the problem.